# error: 150 en foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

Al momento de crear esta tabla en mi database
me sale el siguiente error:

> error: 150 "foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

¿Cuál es el problema?

```
create table iddistrito(
disnom varchar(30)
);

create table idcargo(
cargonom varchar(20)
);

create table idempleado(
nombres varchar(30),
apellidos varchar(30),
direccion varchar(30),
telefono char(9),
dni char(8),
sexo char(1),
estadocivil char(1),
sueldo FLOAT(5),
correo varchar(30),
disnom varchar(30),
cargonom varchar(20),
foreign key(disnom)
references iddistrito(disnom),
foreign key(cargonom)
references idcargo(cargonom)
);
```

Comment: Por favor el código como texto para poder ayudarte

Comment: Sigue como texto amiga, te recomiendo pegarlo y seleccionarlo para presionar `ctrl  + k` para darle formato

Comment: lo puse en imagen

Comment: listo, ya lo hize. pero creo que no se actualiza

Comment: Muchas gracias ayudo mucho la edición

Answer (score 2):

- Tu referencia de `FOREIGN KEY` debe apuntar a una columna en otra tabla que este declarada de forma explícita como `PRIMARY KEY`
- Declara a las columnas `disnom` y `cargonom` como llaves primarias

Tus primeras 2 tablas deberían verse de este modo:

```
create table iddistrito(
disnom VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY 
);
create table idcargo(
cargonom VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

- Como punto final recomiendo que a tus llaves foráneas les asignes un nombre de tal modo que sean identificables; así:

Código

```
CONSTRAINT fk_idempleado_iddistrito FOREIGN KEY(disnom) references iddistrito(disnom),
CONSTRAINT fk_idempleado_idcargo FOREIGN key(cargonom) references idcargo(cargonom)
```

Tu script completo debería verse así:

```
create table iddistrito(
disnom VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY 
);
create table idcargo(
cargonom VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY
);

create table idempleado(
nombres varchar(30),
apellidos varchar(30),
direccion varchar(30),
telefono char(9),
dni char(8),
sexo char(1),
estadocivil char(1),
sueldo FLOAT(5),
correo varchar(30),
disnom VARCHAR(30),
cargonom VARCHAR(20),
CONSTRAINT fk_idempleado_iddistrito FOREIGN KEY(disnom) references iddistrito(disnom),
CONSTRAINT fk_idempleado_idcargo FOREIGN key(cargonom) references idcargo(cargonom)
);
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!! :D